# iText7のParagraphで、先頭のスペースを残す方法を教えて下さい

Tags: java, pdf

iText5のChunkを、iText7のParagraphに変更します。
Paragraphにすると先頭のスペースが削除されます。現行の帳票はスペースで行間隔を合わせているので、スペースが削除されるとレイアウトが壊れます。スペースを残す設定、方法はないのでしょうか。

Paragraphの仕様でスペースは削除されることは他の質問で確認しました。

Answer (score 0):

下記を参考にし、自己解決しました。

Is there any way to keep whitespaces before text in iText7?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970739/is-there-any-way-to-keep-whitespaces-before-text-in-itext7

段落の前にNULL文字を追加することで左トリムを防ぐことができました。
NULLは、 "\u0000"が文字化けしたので、"\u00a0"にしました。

変更前　：　Paragraph p = new Paragraph(line).setFont(font);
変更後　：　Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add("\u00a0").add(line).setFont(font);

ただし、使用するフォントによりファイルが壊れます。

OK　：　PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("migu-1m-regular.ttf", "Identity-H");
NG　：　PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("HeiseiKakuGo-W5", "UniJIS-UCS2-H");